# Connect Yii2 to another RESTful application

Tags: rest, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a Yii2 application. I would like to connect it to another restful webpage. So user will send data to my application, I will send them via POST request and do something according to a JSON response. How can I do the send a request / fetch response part in a yii2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best method would be to use curl to make end to end calls to your RESTful API, in which case you may be interested in checking out [a yii2 extension for curl.](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-curl/)

Without a Yii2 extension, we can accomplish this by creating a more general function in a controller or more preferably a model (for shared access)  as exampled below:

```
/**
 * $method e.g POST, GET, PUT 
 * $data = [
        'param' => 'value',
   ]
 */

public function curlToRestApi($method, $url, $data = null)
{
    $curl = curl_init();

    // switch $method
    switch ($method) {
        case 'POST':
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

            if($data !== null) {
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            }
            break;
            // logic for other methods of interest
            // .
            // .
            // .

        default:
            if ($data !== null){
                $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
            }
    }

    // Authentication [Optional]
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    return $result;
}
```

We then call this function on a need basis i.e. depending on the `method` and `url` and/or `data`.

It is also conveniently easy to use `file_get_contents` if fopen wrapper is enabled in order to access Web Service URLs.

```
$response = file_get_contents('http://example.com/path/to/api?param1=stack&param2=overflow');
```

If a JSON response is served, you can recover the php array as follows:

```
$response  = json_decode($response, TRUE);
```

If an XML response is returned, then

```
$response = new \SimpleXMLElement($response);
```

However, if the API endpoint returns an HTTP error status, the file_get_contents function fails with a warning and returns null.